# Touchscreen : how to choose?

Tags: touchscreen

I am working on a small touchscreen extension to implement into a robot (show debug, command some basic functions, show points on a map where the robot has to go, etc...).
Microcontrollers used are Cortex M3.

I am pretty new to the world of touchscreens and I see there are different types and I very don't know how to choose them, and on which criterion.
Astonishing colours or resolution aren't needed, just need something reliable and handy.
A size of about 5", 4:3 format should be great I think, but I will happily look at any suggestion.

Can you help me to choose, tell me where to buy, which price, indicate some references, tips ?
Do you also have some advices about how to interface it ?

Thanks a lot for your help,
Ryl

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't know that.
But anyway, it isn't all part of the question. My whole problem is how to choose a touch screen, on which criterion I should base my choice knowing what is needed.
Could you answer that, apart of the 'shopping' part of the question ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: one person reading it as something that needs to be closed is not world ending, it takes 5 people and there is still room to discuss it. The issue you are running into here is you are asking many questions, many really. I see 5 questions, some related, some not. Advice about how to interface is almost completely separate, maybe after you find a screen ask specific to that screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I had to choose a touchscreen for my project I rather prefer a capacitive one. Resistive touch screens may be cheaper but have some disadvantages comparing with capacitive ones:

- They need calibration
- Are less sensitive
- Have shorter life cycle

One of the downsides of the capacitive touch screens used to be the complexity of the required software and hardware, but there are already capacitive touch screen display controllers that solve this issue.

Take a look at [NHD-5.0-800480TF-ATXI#-CTP](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/new-capacitive-touch-tft-nhd50800480tfatxictp-p-5018.html) from Newhaven Display, it may be what you are looking for.

It includes a controller with I<sup>2</sup>C interface and it seems fairly simple to use.

[image]

Comment: although helpful this site is intended to help people in the long term, please instead explain how you would go about finding a screen.

Comment: Just edited the answer.

Comment: that looks like a great start. It lets me know about the decisions involved in capacitive versus resistive, how about choosing past that point. As you edit please note at 10 it will make your answer CW, at that point just flag us and we can remove it. I would like to know more about how you found the screen having already made your capacitive choice.

Comment: Actually I never had the need to use touch screens in my projects so I'm not an expert on touch screens. I found this screen because I've been working with other displays from the same manufacturer and a few months ago I got a notification about these new displays and I thought it would fit Ryl requirements.

Comment: Dont have to be an expert to answer how to find one. Might be interesting for you to research, might not, that is your choice, I gave you a +1 for putting some decent effort into it.

Comment: I want to help your formatting to make your answer jump out more but I am having formatting block so I will just have to try to check in later.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. English is not my main language so any help is welcome.

Comment: Your communication is very clear, I just wanted to pretty it up, more of being used to SE thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bruno, for your answer (and thanks Kortuk for your useful comments).
This screen is exactly what I need. I just took the 3.5" version for integration in a small robot.